# what version of Jenkins is suitable for Java 10

Tags: java, jenkins

I am trying to Install Jenkins for my automation. In the command prompt when i type

`java -jar jenkins.war` in my directory it gives me following error

```
Mar 27, 2019 3:19:21 PM Main verifyJavaVersion
SEVERE: Running with Java class version 54 which is not in the list of supported versions: [52, 55]. Run with the --enable-future-java flag to enable such behavior. See https://jenkins.io/redirect/java-support/
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: 54.0
        at Main.verifyJavaVersion(Main.java:174)
        at Main.main(Main.java:142)

Jenkins requires Java versions [8, 11] but you are running with Java 10 from C:\Program Files\Java\jre-10.0.2
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: 54.0
        at Main.verifyJavaVersion(Main.java:174)
        at Main.main(Main.java:142)

C:\Jenkins>
```

It says Java 10 is not supported, please help me find which version is good for Java 10.

Comment: This question seems like it may be off topic for https://superuser.com/help/on-topic I would recommend deleting the question and asking on https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

> It says Java 10 is not supported, please help me find which version is good for Java 10.

A version of Jenkins that supports Java 10 does not exist.  You will have to install one of the Java versions that Jenkins supports.  You could, in theory, make the necessary changes to Jenkins yourself to support Java 10.  That, of course, would be an extremely difficult task for a single developer.

> - Java 8 runtime environments, both 32-bit and 64-bit versions are supported
> - Jenkins 2.164 and 2.164.1 support Java 11 runtime environments

Source: [Java requirements](https://jenkins.io/doc/administration/requirements/java/)

You should just install Java 8 or Java 11 in order to use Jenkins and use Java 10 for everything else.